# javaFX getting nullpointer exception when trying to set BarChart from different controller

Tags: java, javafx-8

In my JavaFx application I want to update my BarChart whenever calculate button is clicked. The problem is that I am getting:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   application.StatController.setActivityData(StatController.java:47)

It is always pointing to:`xAxis.setCategories(optionsNames);
But it has elements on the list (See printscreen:https://image.ibb.co/b9YO8Q/Capture.png

In my StatController class I have setActivityData which is called from FormController class.

StatController class:

```
public class StatController {

    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Double> barChart;
    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis xAxis;
    Activities activities = new Activities();
    private Map<String, List<Double>> uniqueActivityOptions = new HashMap<>();      
    private ObservableList<String> optionsNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList();      

    public StatController(){}

    @FXML
    private void initialize() { 
    }

    public void setActivityData(Activities activitiesList) {
        for(Activity activity : activities.getActivityList()) {
            String optionName = activity.getOption();
            if(uniqueActivityOptions.containsKey(optionName)) {
                uniqueActivityOptions.get(optionName).add((double) activity.getNumber());
            } else {
                List<Double> activityOptionList = new ArrayList<>();
                activityOptionList.add((double) activity.getNumber());
                uniqueActivityOptions.put(optionName, activityOptionList);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Double>> entry : uniqueActivityOptions.entrySet()) {
            optionsNames.add(entry.getKey());
        }

        xAxis.setCategories(optionsNames);

        XYChart.Series<String, Double> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Double>> entry : uniqueActivityOptions.entrySet()) {
            Double average = calculateAverage(entry.getValue());
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(entry.getKey().toString(), average));
        }   
        barChart.getData().add(series); 
    }
    private double calculateAverage(List<Double> values) {
        double result = 0;
        for (Double value : values) {
            result += value;
        }
        return result / values.size();
    }
}
```

FormController class:

```
public class FormController {

    Activities act = new Activities();
    List<Activity> activities = act.getActivityList();

    private ObservableList<String> opt = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Option 1",
                "Option 2",
                "Option 3"
            );
    @FXML
    private Button calculateButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField numberField;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> options;
    private String selectedOption;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        options.getItems().addAll(opt);
        options.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
        .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                selectedOption = newValue;  
            }

        }); 
    }
    @FXML
    public void calculateButtonClicked(){   
        activities.add(new Activity(selectedOption, Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText())));
        StatController  sc = new StatController();
        sc.setActivityData(act);
    }
}
```

I tested setActivityData method in StatsController and it is working correctly when I am passing Activities.

Please advise what to change in the code to pass and update BarChart.
I know that this is something trivial but I really don't know how to do it.

`
Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: It's the exact same as every other NPE question asked. Where do you initialize xAxis variable in the code that throws the NPE? Where do you ever assign to it a viable reference?

Comment: I know what is nullpointerexception but the strings in ObservableList are passed to xAxis.setCategories(optionsNames). xAxis is initialized by @FXML which is used in JavaFX. You can see that list of observables are passed from ObservableList to xAxis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in `FormController#calculateButtonClicked()`. You create a new instance of `StatController` manually and then call the `setActivityData()` method. This is not how JavaFX works and will result in the `xAxis` member being null, hence your `NullPointerException`.

Controller members annotated with the `@FXML` annotation will be injected by the `FXMLLoader` class when you call the `FXMLLoader#load()` method. You will need to use the `FXMLLoader` class to load the .fxml file that corresponds to the `StatController` class, which will then create an instance of your `StatController` object for you and will also inject your *xAxis* and *barChart* instances.

Here's a quick (not production ready) example that you will have to adapt for your specific scenario:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(filePath); // your path to the .fxml file
loader.load();
StatController controller = (StatController) loader.getController();
controller.setActivityData(activities); // your activities data
```

How and when you do that depends on how your scene graph is setup. Looking at your source code, I would suggest the following changes:

MainController.java

```
public class MainController
        implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;
    @FXML
    private Tab formTabPage;
    @FXML
    private FormController formTabController; // change name to this
    @FXML
    private Tab statsTabPage;
    @FXML
    private StatController statsTabController; // change name to this

    private MainApp mainApp;


    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {

        this.mainApp = mainApp;
    }


    @Override // rename your init() method to this
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        // add this line
        formTabController.setStatController(statTabController);
    }
}
```

FormController.java

```
public class FormController {


    Activities act = new Activities();
    List<Activity> activities = act.getActivityList();

    private ObservableList<String> opt = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Option 1",
            "Option 2",
            "Option 3"
    );
    @FXML
    private Button calculateButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField numberField;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> options;
    private String selectedOption;
    private StatController statController; // add this member


    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        options.getItems().addAll(opt);
        options.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
                .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {

                        selectedOption = newValue;
                    }
                });
    }


    @FXML
    public void calculateButtonClicked() {
        // change this method here
        statController.setActivityData(act);
    }

    // add this method here
    public void setStatController(StatController statController) {

        this.statController = statController;
    }
}
```

There are other problems that occur, but this fixes your null pointer exception. The reason this works and your previous code didn't, is because you were manually creating a new instance of `StatController` and not using the instance that the `FXMLLoader` had already loaded and mapped to the user interface node for you. All I have done above, is capture a reference to the controller you needed, and provided it to the other through a setter method.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this in my project. Do you think you could check my git repository[link](https://github.com/ErniMJ/JavaFx/tree/master/src/application) and give me a hint what to change?

Comment: @erni I have updated my answer after looking at your source code. I had some trouble copying/pasting in the changes I made, so if I messed something up, let me know.

Comment: just tested and it is working!!! Thanks for showing me how I can use it in future!.